How can I migrate from an electron app to an electron app with vite and react
I have a project that is done using electron forge and basic css and html how can I migrate this project to electron-vite with react for the front end. I have tried using the @electron-forge/plugin-vite. I followed the documentation exactly as they said but I am never able to get it to find the module Error: Could not find module with name: @electron-forge/plugin-vite. Make sure it's listed in the devDependencies of your package.json . And I can clearly see the plugin in the devDependencies
"devDependencies": {
    "@electron-forge/cli": "^6.4.2",
    "@electron-forge/maker-dmg": "^6.4.2",
    "@electron-forge/maker-pkg": "^6.4.2",
    "@electron-forge/maker-zip": "^6.4.2",
    "@electron-forge/plugin-auto-unpack-natives": "^6.4.2",
    "@electron-forge/plugin-vite": "^7.4.0",
    "@electron-forge/publisher-s3": "^6.4.2",
    "@electron/rebuild": "^3.6.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "electron": "^30.1.0",
    "node-abi": "^3.64.0"
  },

Thank you for any help you might have.
I tried using the plugin but it did not work.
